# MySQL Query to Count Unique Domains from Email Address field

Tags: mysql, sql, email, count, dns

I'd like to get a better idea of what domains my customers are using. I could easily do this in PHP by `explode`ing each address and counting the domain that way. But I'm wondering if there's a way to get this information with just a plain MySQL query?

This is what sample output would look like:

`gmail.com | 3942`

`yahoo.com | 3852`

`hotmail.com | 209`

... and so on, where the first column is the email addresses domain, and the 2nd column is the number of addresses at that domain.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You would have to do something like this:

```
SELECT substring_index(email, '@', -1) domain, COUNT(*) email_count
FROM table
GROUP BY substring_index(email, '@', -1)

-- If you want to sort as well:
ORDER BY email_count DESC, domain;
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding ORDER BY to WoLpH's answer makes the output more clear:

```
SELECT substring_index(email, '@', -1), COUNT(*) AS MyCount
FROM `database`.`table`
GROUP BY substring_index(email, '@', -1)
ORDER BY MyCount DESC;
```

Comment: Did you miss [WoLpH's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2440458/104223)? The same was suggested two years ago ;-)

Comment: Yes. I added ORDER BY MyCount DESC; I would have loved to add it to his as a commment but do not yet have 50 reputation... I obviously could have made this more clear in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, an explanation might help stave off down votes. Btw, I did not down vote your response since it was valid. I do wish they would relax the whole 50 point restriction thing .. since it frequently produces the opposite of the desired effect. A lot of people do exactly what you did. ie post answers because they cannot comment yet. Catch 22.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email) + 1,LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX ('@', Email)), Count(*) from Tbl_name
Group by SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email) + 1,LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX ('@', Email))
order by Count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Small tweak to Wolph's original above to shorten a bit and add nice column name and limit results in case list is long. Adjust limit to your own liking

```
select substring_index(email, '@', -1) AS domain, count(*) from TABLE group by domain order by count(*) DESC limit 40;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get Unique count of domain from table.

```
SELECT substr(email,INSTR(email,"@")+1),count(substr(email,INSTR(email,"@"))) from YOUR_TABLE group by substr(email,INSTR(email,"@"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    substring_index(email_address, '@', -1) AS Domain 
   ,COUNT(*) AS MyCount
FROM 
    database_name.table_name
GROUP BY 
    substring_index(email_address, '@', -1)
ORDER BY
    MyCount DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

How about something like

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [what you want])
FROM MyTable
```

[COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)

Comment: i'm not sure what the expression would be to separate the parts of the email address into user and domain portions.