# MySQL select query with largest possible distribution

Tags: php, mysql, select, distribution

I'm feeding a postfix queue with mail addresses selected randomly (which are tied to the actual newsletter). Postfix is healthy queue is nice yet i still want to do it a little smarter.

I am trying to figure out a MySQL query which selects email addresses not randomly but by the largest possible dispersion. Is it possible to do a such thing with a single query? Or i need to [count different providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440429/mysql-query-to-count-unique-domains-from-email-address-field) then slice the results and select addresses again?
The latter seems silly enough, the first approach would be better.

Maybe just bad search queries but i can't find a similar problem/solution.

Thanks in advance,

fabrik

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'dispersion'?

Comment: @ethrbunny edited my question, maybe distribution is a better term.

Comment: Maybe a dispersion is meant by one email address from each possible (registered) domain/email provider? So one email address from gmail.com, one from yahoo.com, etc - but random per each provider?

Comment: I guess you could use a 'select distinct ' with some string parsing to get the domain. Group these and then pull a random entry from each group.

Comment: @ethrbunny could you provide some pseudo code please?

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way: alter Your DB table and add another column called e.g. `email_provider`.
During the registration to the newsletter You can using PHP extract the email provider from registering email address and store it to this column so the values should be `yahoo.com`, `gmail.com` etc...

Also You would have to create a script that will walk the table row by row and update this coulmn with value from email address to persist the data consistency.

This shouldn't be hard to achieve...

Then call a query where You `group by email_provider`, `order by rand()` and select just one email address per each grouped provider...

And You should be done...

Comment: Selecting provides isn't the problem but selecting subscribers based on providers. I don't want to bloat my table with redundant data (providers). Selecting one subscriber per provider is unnaceptable (altough i can select 2, 3 more i know). I'd like to select these different providers as equal distribution as i can.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was my fault i've overlooked the problem a little bit.

**pseudo query:**

```
SELECT `subscriber`.`id`, `subscriber`.`email`, `queue`.`subscriber`, 
SUBSTRING(`email`, LOCATE('@', `email`)) AS `domain`,
COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM `queue`
LEFT JOIN `subscriber` ON `queue`.`subscriber` = `subscriber`.`id`
GROUP BY `domain`
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

And voilá, distributed e-mail providers!