# MySQL Query for domains and post numbers

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL DB table `users` where two of its columns have `email` addresses and `post` counts for each member from a forum.

I can pull the total of users registered with specific email domains with following:

```
SELECT substring_index(email, '@', -1), COUNT(*) AS emailcounts
FROM `users`
GROUP BY substring_index(email, '@', -1)
ORDER BY emailcounts DESC;
```

and the results from this query give me the following:

```
gmail.com 147
yahoo.com 112
hotmail.com 101
aol.com 98
live.com 84
```

Where e.g. 147 is the number of users who have registered through gmail.com

My question is:

What would be the correct MySQL query, so when you run it against the `users` table by selecting `email` and `post` columns, the results would also include the total sum of posts from users with email domains like below:

```
gmail.com 147  1559
yahoo.com 112  972
hotmail.com 101  833
aol.com 98  612
live.com 84  420
```

E.g. From 147 users who registered from gmail.com we have a TOTAL 1559 posts

I tried now with several options [discussed here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440429/mysql-query-to-count-unique-domains-from-email-address-field) , but I cannot make it work as above

I hope this edit helps in explaining the situation.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: need more information to try your third column data, what is that?

Comment: explain it better...table structures, what fields you want to select, what are the expecting results

Comment: Original post edited with further information. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me this would work:

SELECT substring_index(email, '@', -1), COUNT(*) AS emailcounts,sum(post_counts)
FROM `users`
GROUP BY substring_index(email, '@', -1)
ORDER BY emailcounts DESC;

Replace post_counts with the correct column name.

Comment: Excellent. Just as I asked for. Thank you.