# count of distincts substring in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a query that count (or at least retrieve) distincts occurrences of a substring in a column.

I have one column that is like this:

elem1=value1|elem2=value2|elem3=value3

I want to retrieve distincts values of elem2 and the number of ocurrences.

```
SELECT
    substring(
        column , LOCATE( 'elem2=' , column ) + $1 , $2 
    ) AS a ,
    COUNT(*) b ,
FROM
   column ORDER BY a;
```

Thanks

Comment: Storing multiple values in one field is almost ever a sign of bad database design. Especially if you've got to work with single ones. It's worse, if those values aren't even character separated ...

Comment: Arghhhhh!!!! Tony runs away screaming.

Comment: This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440429/mysql-query-to-count-unique-domains-from-email-address-field/2440458#2440458

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve the specified result.

<strike>SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.col,'elem2=',-1),'|',1))
      FROM t
     WHERE t.col LIKE '%elem2=%'</strike>

Apparently, I misread the question (the query above returns a count of distinct values. Or, I just lost track of the specified result, while I was working on the tedious string parsing.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.col,'elem2=',-1),'|',1) AS a
     , COUNT(*) AS b
  FROM t
 WHERE t.col LIKE '%elem2=%'
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.col,'elem2=',-1),'|',1)
 ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.col,'elem2=',-1),'|',1)
```

---

**NOTE:**

Note that SQL wasn't really designed for parsing values out of strings.

The normative relational pattern for this type of data would to create a table, with columns named `elem1`, `elem2`, `elem3`, and to store each separate value in a column.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE t 
( id     INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, elem1  VARCHAR(80)
, elem2  VARCHAR(80)
, elem3  VARCHAR(80)
);
INSERT INTO t (elem1, elem2, elem3) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```

To get a count of distinct values in `elem2` column, we'd do something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT elem2)
  FROM t
```

To get the distinct values of elem2 along with the count of occurrences

```
SELECT elem2    AS a
     , COUNT(*) AS b
  FROM t
 GROUP BY elem2
 ORDER BY elem2
```

That's essentially the same as the query at the beginning of my answer; the first query just has to do the parsing the `'elem2=value2'` out of the string.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: I originally had "do the heavy lifting of parsing", but it's more than just the parsing. The hideous performance won't be noticed with small sets; it only becomes apparent with larger sets. We're anticipating the followup question to be: "Why is my query so slow?"

Comment: @spencer7593: I have been given that DB recently and it's productive, so it can't be redesigned (at least for now), but I can see the problem of this design.
Thanks for the answer, however (as I understand it) it's counting all the rows that has "elem2=" , but all rows have that substring.
What I need is show the diferents values of elem2, and show the occurrence of each of that values.
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @chomsky: I've already updated the answer; the original query answered a different question (a count of distinct values); I've replaced that with a query that returns a list of distinct values, and a count of occurrences. I wasn't saying that you had to re-design the database; I've had situations like this where I was provided a file, and it was easier to load it into the database as it was, and use SQL to process it. That's why the question is worthy of an answer. I meant to suggest that a normative relational design would help avoid the tedious syntax.

Comment: @chomsky: I'm sorry for you and others in such a position. I appreciate the solution of spencer7593 but I won't encourage anyone to *begin* with such a design. But they do ... and people like you have to pay for it.